# Piping a stream with "end" set to "false" resolves before writable stream is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a function that returns a resolved promise after piping a readable stream. There are two pipes. The first pipe is a transform, and the second pipe is a writable stream.  I do not want the writable stream to be closed, so I pass `{end:false}` in the writer/pipe argument. The transform and writable stream work independently (ie one pipe only) but not when I chain them.

As per all examples I've seen, in order to know when the process is complete I added `readable.on('end')`. It is not working as expected.

```
pipe(readable, transform, writable){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        readable
            .pipe(transform)
            .pipe(writable, {end:false})
            .on('error', (error) => {
                console.error(error)
                reject(error);
            })
        readable.on('end', () => {
                writable.end();
                resolve();
            });
    });
}
```

1. If I call `writable.end()` nothing is written to the file
2. If I don't call `writable.end()` it actually does exactly what it is supposed to do, BUT it resolves the promise way too early.. the file is still being written to.
3. If I don't use `{end:false}` and just do this normally, it works fine. The problem is I want the writable stream to stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every event, it is the `writable.on('unpipe')` handler that I needed to indicate writing was done.

```
pipe(readable, transform, writable){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        readable
            .pipe(transform)
            .pipe(writable, {end:false})
            .on('unpipe', () => {
                 resolve();
                 // this must be called somewhere!
                 // writable.end();
             })
            .on('error', (error) => {
                console.error(error)
                reject(error);
            })
    });
}
```